# R parallel computing (parSapply) elapsed time is much longer than NOT using parallel

Tags: r, parallel-processing, sapply

I am running some R programs, and thought parallel computing, parSapply(), was much faster. However, I noticed that the elapsed time is much longer comparing to NOT using parallel, i.e., sapply(), although the "user time" is much more shorter. It seems that NOT using parallel is a good choice, but I am confused why the elapsed time is so long. Is there a way to reduce the elapsed time and make it close to user time? Below is the recorded system time. My CPU is Intel i7-4770.

Using sapply:

```
  user  system elapsed 
16.048   0.000  16.092
```

Using parSapply():

```
 user  system elapsed 
2.740   0.464  45.553
```

Comment: There's overhead to communicate with each worker. In general, parallel works best when each iteration takes a long time to finish, and performs worst when there are many iterations of fast operations.

Comment: Thanks! It's good to know the pros and cons.